# How to display row once if all data is the same

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query below:

```
$questionquery = "
SELECT DISTINCT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, r.ReplyType, 
q.QuestionMarks, q.SessionId
FROM Answer an 
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId and an.SessionId = q.SessionId
JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
WHERE ".implode(" AND ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "q.QuestionContent LIKE ?"))."
GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
ORDER BY ".implode(", ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ?, 1, 0) DESC"))."
";
```

Now below is what each database table looks like:

Session Table:

```
SessionId  SessionName
1          AAA
2          AAB
3          AAC
```

Question Table:

```
SessionId  QuestionId QuestionContent              ReplyId OptionId
1          1          Here is a single answer      2       1
2          3          Here is a single answer      2       1
3          3          Here is a single answer      2       1
```

Answer Table:

```
AnswerId  SessionId QuestionId Answer
1         1         1          True
2         2         3          True
3         3         3          True
```

Reply Table:

```
ReplyId  ReplyType
1        Single
2        Multiple
```

Option Table:

```
OptionId  OptionType
1         True or False
```

Now the problem I am getting is that in the database, I have three questions which are exactly the same and have the same answer, same marks, same option type etc, all the same which is fine. But in the query I what I want to do is that if there are multiple rows whose columns are all matching, then only display it once. So at the moment it is displaying this below as the query output:

```
Here is a single answer     True or False   1   True    Multiple    5   
Here is a single answer     True or False   1   True    Multiple    5   
Here is a single answer     True or False   1   True    Multiple    5
```

But as all the details of the question is the same, it should only display it once like below:

```
Here is a single answer     True or False   1   True    Multiple    5
```

How can I get the query to display the row once if there are multiple rows with exactly the same data?

**UPDATE:**

```
   $questionquery = "
SELECT DISTINCT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, Answer, r.ReplyType, 
q.QuestionMarks
 FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, r.ReplyType, 
q.QuestionMarks, q.SessionId
FROM Answer an 
INNER JOIN Question q ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId and an.SessionId = q.SessionId
JOIN Reply r ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
WHERE ".implode(" AND ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "q.QuestionContent LIKE ?"))."
GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
)
AS tmpresult
ORDER BY ".implode(", ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ?, 1, 0) DESC"))."
";
```

Comment: @Joddy Where do I add limit 1 in query?

Comment: After _ORDER BY <CONDITIONS> DESC_ 

**ADD** 

_LIMIT 1_

Comment: ORDER BY ".implode(", ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "IF(q.QuestionContent LIKE ?, 1, 0) DESC"))." LIMIT 1";

Comment: @Joddy Sorry for lateness, if I add LIMIT 1, then problem is that it only shows one row for anything that matches with where clause. For example if I have 3 different questions which all contain the word `single` then it will only show one of the 3 questions, even though they are all different questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mighty be crazy idea, but still worth of try, make a subquery from your main query and do another select from it with DISTINCT:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT {yourcolumns}
 FROM
 (
        your current code
 ) as tmp
```

Comment: I will include an update in my question in 5 minutes, in the update is that how you wanted me to code it.

Comment: Can you please remove GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer ORDER BY Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer because it is being already calculated in sub query

Comment: Hi, tried this but no luck, it is giving me this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DISTINCT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, GROUP_CONCAT(DIS' at line 5 `. Code updated in question so you can see what it now looks like

Comment: Try moving order by outside of sub query.

Comment: And also make sure to change curly brackets "{" to normal ones "(", also give an alias to sub query by "as tmpresult"

Comment: Code updated, I am getting this error:`Warning: mysqli::prepare(): (42S22/1054): Unknown column 'q.QuestionContent' in 'field list' in /.../ on line 81 Error preparing statement: Unknown column 'q.QuestionContent' in 'field list'`

Comment: figured out whole problem, I just needed to remove `q.SessionId` from select statement, no sub queries needed

Answer (score 0):

Expand your `GROUP BY` clause to add those columns by which you want to consider as row as duplicate something like below

```
GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId, QuestionContent,  
         OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, Answer, q.QuestionMarks
```